# Shared memory IPC - Segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, ipc, shared-memory

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/msg.h>
#include<sys/ipc.h>
#include<sys/shm.h>
#include<string.h>
int main(){
    int key=99;
    char a[1000]="ASDASDAS";
    int fd=shmget(key,sizeof(char)*1000,IPC_CREAT|0666);
    char *b=malloc(sizeof(char)*1000);
    b=shmat(fd,NULL,0);
    strcpy(b,"haha");
    //sprintf(b,"aloha!\0");
    if (fork()==0){
        char *c=NULL;
        int fd2=shmget(key,sizeof(char)*100,0);
        c=shmat(fd2,NULL,0);
        printf("ceva%s\n",c);



    }


    return 0;

}
```

Basically what I am trying to do "send" an string via shared memory, but I get an error, segmentation fault , it has something to do with the pointers and with the strcpy I believe, could someone explain me why it doesn't work ?

Thanks a lot,

Comment: Your `malloc` is being thrown away, but that's not at issue. Did you check the return of `shmat` against `(void*)-1`?

Comment: Now would be a good time to add some error checking in your code - you have absolutely none, so you will be oblivious to any failures in your system calls.

Comment: i didn't do that because I use the same key, and in the past I have a problem with using the same key, it gave me -1 ...

Comment: why am i not getting any segfault with the same code on x86-64bit gcc 4.4.3??output is cevahaha .

Comment: well I compile it and run it on my Mac from terminal ... gcc 4.2

Comment: If you get errors, it means something didn't work.  You don't ignore the error; you work out what the source of the error is.  Here, you don't destroy the shared memory segment before exiting, so it will be available the next time the program is run — shared memory segments can exist even if no process is using them.

Comment: After adding the suggested error checking, at the least all the return values of the shm calls, recompile the code with warnings enabled (-Wall etc) and debug symbols (-g) and run it in a debugger.

Comment: You were right it was the key, after changing it it works flawlessly, thank you